# How to perform detail packet capture on Ubuntu firewall?

Tags: networking, security, firewall, port-forwarding, packet-analyzer

I've routed internet traffic of my other systems on this ubuntu linux system where I have configured packet forwarding. but still I am unable to get internet on other systems.

Hence I want to perform packet capture to see if routing is happening correctly and all internet traffic is coming to this system. So that I can find out whether the issue is with Ubuntu system or the router which is forwarding internet trafic to this system. I want all the packets to be captured irrespective of whether that packet was allowed, dropped, blocked.

So how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iptables is not the best tool for packet capturing and I am not sure that capturing packets will answer your (routing) questions.

You can use one of many tools, wireshark, snort, or tcpdump (to name a few). Your router may be able to track / log this as well.

The details of packets is moderately complex and somewhat lengthy to expalain. Take a look at the existing documentation and ask a more specific question. As this is not ubuntu specific, you may be directed to other stack exchange Q&A - Unix and Linux for example.

http://www.slashroot.in/packet-capturing-tcpdump-command-linux

http://wiki.wireshark.org/Tools

http://www.tecmint.com/12-tcpdump-commands-a-network-sniffer-tool/